# Cannot clear mat-autocomplete selected option when deleting input text

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have two mat-autocomplete, when I choose an option from the first, the second is loaded depending on that first mat-autocomplete option. After I select an option from the second mat-autocomplete, if I just clear the first mat just by removing the text, the (optionSelected) doesn't proceed and thus, doesn't clear the second mat options. I struggle on how to create an event to clean the second mat-autocomplete options when the user delete by hand (text) the option from the first mat.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="form-element">
  <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Locación" formControlName="locacion" [matAutocomplete]="locacion">
  <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['locacion'].valid">
    {{ titleAlert }}
  </mat-error>
  <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #locacion="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayLocacion" (optionSelected)="cargarRutas()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let locacion of locaciones | async" [value]="locacion">
      {{locacion.nombre}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="form-element">
  <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Ruta" formControlName="ruta" [matAutocomplete]="ruta">
  <mat-error *ngIf="!formGroup.controls['ruta'].valid">
    {{ titleAlert }}
  </mat-error>
  <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #ruta="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayRuta">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let ruta of rutas | async" [value]="ruta">
      {{ruta.nombre}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
  async cargarRutas() {
    if (this.formGroup.controls['locacion'].valid) {
      this.cargaRutas = await this.rutaService.getRutasLocacion(this.formGroup.get('locacion').value.id)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `valueChanges` emitted when you change the value of a `FormControl` with

```
this.subscription = this.formGroup.get('locacion').valueChanges.subscribe(value => { 
  if (!!value.id) {
     this.cargaRutas = await this.rutaService.getRutasLocacion(value.id)
  } else {
     this.cargaRutas = [];
  }
});
```

In the if condition you can even put `typeof value === 'object'`; Don't forget you have to unsubscribe from all observables that doesn't complete itself. So implement the OnDestroy interface and

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```